# Convert a parameter according to Database in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

Here i got value for `catname` from parameter as `movie` but in database its have corresponding value as 1, same for music->2, game->3....

```
      "WHERE (\n" +
                            "\t\t(`Post`.`status` = 1)\n" +

                            "\t\tAND (`Post`.`postto_id` =\"+catname+\" \")\n" +
                            "\t\t)" +
                            "ORDER BY `Post`.`id` desc LIMIT 5", new CrelistMapper());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }

private class CrelistMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<List<Creativity>> {
        public List<Creativity> extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {


            List<Creativity> crelistList = new ArrayList<Creativity>();

            while (resultSet.next()) {


                Creativity userObject = new Creativity(resultSet.getString("**postto_id**"),
```

Here i got value as movie in "**postto_id**" how can i convert it into 1 instead of movies from parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for parse int from Integer class.

```
import java.lang.Integer;

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String stringId = "1";

        int intFromString = Integer.parseInt(stringId);

        System.out.println(intFromString);
    }
}
```

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) for a version of the overloaded method that meets your purpose